# Different Growth Rates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So this is a slightly trickier growth rate problem but I think I solved it, I just want to confirm my answer. The question:

---

A population of bacteria is initially $N_0$ and grows at a constant rate $R_0$. Suppose $\tau$ hours later the bacteria is put into a different culture such that it now grows at the constant rate $R_1$. Determine the population of bacteria for all time.

---

I believe the solution is $$N(t) = N_0 e^{R_0 t} \;\;\;\;\;\; t<\tau$$ $$N(t)=(N_0e^{R_0 \tau})e^{R_1 t} \;\;\;\;\;\; t \geq \tau$$

Is that correct or at least on the right track or is it completely off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last one, observe the time grown at rate $R_1$, starting at population $N_0^\prime=N_0e^{R_0\tau}$, is $t^\prime=t-\tau$. Hence, for $t\geq \tau$, you should get
$$
N(t)=N_0^\prime e^{R_1 t^\prime} = N_0e^{R_0\tau}e^{R_1 (t-\tau)}.
$$
As a sanity check, at $t=\tau$ both the first regime and the second should give the same value (and, of course, at $t=0$ you should get $N_0$).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Clement said, I would just change it to look like:

$$N(t) = N_0 e^{R_0 (t-t_0)} \;\;\;\;\;\; t_0 \leq t<\tau$$
$$N(t)=(N_0e^{R_0 (\tau - t_0)})e^{R_1 (t-\tau)} = N(\tau) e^{R_1 (t-\tau)} \;\;\;\;\;\; \tau \leq t$$

Since the book you are getting this problem from tends to use $t_0$ as a starting time rather than $0$.